# Google's working example for banner ads does not work

Tags: android, admob, ads

I've been trying to get banner ads to show on my app but couldn't figure it out, so I downloaded a working example from Google and to my surprise it doesn't work either. The apps show up just fine but the ads don't load. Is there some Android Studio setting preventing me from doing this?

```
01-22 15:53:35.233    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-22 15:53:35.601    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
01-22 15:53:35.601    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
01-22 15:53:35.821    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/WebViewFactory﹕ Loading com.android.webview version 37 (eng.upndwn4par-arm) (code 199991)
01-22 15:53:35.853    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/LibraryLoader﹕ Loading: webviewchromium
01-22 15:53:35.856    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/LibraryLoader﹕ Time to load native libraries: 4 ms (timestamps 1952-1956)
01-22 15:53:35.857    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
01-22 15:53:35.863    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider﹕ Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {290842f0}
01-22 15:53:35.866    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
01-22 15:53:35.866    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(106)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
01-22 15:53:35.874    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
01-22 15:53:35.874    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-22 15:53:35.918    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(315)] locale_file_path.empty()
01-22 15:53:35.919    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/chromium﹕ [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=26 off=43100 len=2945
01-22 15:53:35.919    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/chromium﹕ [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:36 off:228796 len:643667
01-22 15:53:35.955    8749-8815/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample W/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ Requires BLUETOOTH permission
01-22 15:53:35.955    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/24/14, 167c270, I68fa98814b
01-22 15:53:36.069    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
01-22 15:53:36.085    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/Ads﹕ Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("2EAB96D84FE62876379A9C030AA6A0AC") to get test ads on this device.
01-22 15:53:36.181    8749-8845/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
01-22 15:53:36.188    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
01-22 15:53:36.238    8749-8845/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-22 15:53:36.243    8749-8845/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-22 15:53:46.811    8749-8834/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
01-22 15:53:46.847    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(403)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
01-22 15:53:46.893    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
01-22 15:53:46.897    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
01-22 15:53:46.919    8749-8749/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 0
01-22 15:53:46.939    8749-8823/com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(901)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
```

Comment: on device or on emulator?

Comment: @Elltz On Nexus 5 running 5.0.2

Comment: @Elitz Well after you asked that I tried running it on the emulator. It works. I finally realized I was an idiot as I was running an ad-blocker on my phone. -_-

Comment: great..(smiles)..  4 mins wait, was worth it then, okay, Sir, oh no, you are a genius..

Comment: @geft - Well you had to only wait 4 mins. I browsed around and brainstormed 2 hours before coming across your comment and realizing I have adblocker as well. -_-

Comment: If you have solved your problem you should write about it in the answer box provided. Adding the word "solved" to the question does not cause it to removed from the unsolved question pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running an ad-blocker on my phone.